# Doubt on the infinitive usage

Tags: grammar, british-english, to-infinitive

I've been recently studying the **verb patterns** with which we use the infinitive and the -ing form (e.g. I suggest meeting tomorrow at my house, NOT: I suggest to meet tomorrow at my house).

But later, I came across this situation:
I hope you to have a great time on Saturday.
I hope you have a great time on Saturday.

I put these two sentences on Grammarly, and it told me that the *"to"* in the first one shouldn't be there. It's quirky for me since, in my textbook (which teaches British English), *"hope"* is among the verbs that must go with an infinitive.

Just in case you need to know, my Grammarly account is set to revise British English.

Thank you very much.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following website points out that when we use *hope* for the future, we use "to" plus infinitive only when the subjects of the main and subordinate clauses are the same.

[Perfect English Grammar *how to use hope*](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/hope.html)

> We can use 'to + infinitive' with 'hope' for the future. When we use 'to + infinitive', the subject is the same as the subject of 'hope'.
> *I hope to come to the party tomorrow.* (= I hope I can come to the party tomorrow.)
> *I hope to run a marathon this year.*

In your example,

> I hope you have a great time on Saturday.

the subject of *hope* is *I*, but the subject of *have* is *you*. In the case of different subjects in the main and subordinate clauses, we can use simple present tense to represent the future.
So "hope you to have" is not correct.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; very helpful.